# What is [in] and [out]?

Tags: c++

I came across this code but I have not seen [in] or [out] before. What are they?

```
HRESULT QueryInterface([in] REFIID riid, [out] void **ppvObject) {

}
```

Comment: That looks like IDL rather than C++.  The IDL compiler will generate C or C++ header files from that, without the attributes (or replacing them with comments and macros)

Comment: It is variables being passed `in` and `out` (the return type) by reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As provided in your question, the code probably won't compile. That being said, though not common you might come across code such as:

```
HRESULT QueryInterface(IN REFIID riid, OUT void **ppvObject)
```

which compiles because somewhere IN and OUT are #define'd (to be empty). This is sometimes done with pointers to indicate if the parameters are input (read only), or output (written to), or BOTH. This indication is for the reader's benefit.

Comment: i switched to IN REFIID riid, OUT void **ppvObject and it compiled

Answer (score 4):

These are [directional IDL attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They indicate the direction that data is being passed.

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question, rather than just pointing out that "in means in" and "out means out" as others have done. :)

Answer (score 2):

it's an indication of a value that's being sent `[in]` to a function or, in the case of `[out]` it's being changed and so is an [out]put